# Noticeable differences between usb soundcard and hifiberry XLR

Tags: pi-4, hifiberry

I am recording vocals with an XLR microphone on my Pi 4B and have been using a spare USB soundcard that I have. The current set-up works fine but I just found out about Hifiberry soundcards and just want to know if there are any noticeable differences between a usb soundcard and a hifiberry XLR soundcard with respect to the sound (latency, noise, static, overall sound quality, etc).

Comment: latency, now. noise and static, perhaps - does the microphone output a balanced audio signal? Obviously, if noise and static are decreased using the Hifiberry,, then overall sound quality will be better ... not sure if "etc" will be effected

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm using an AT2020 microphone which output a balanced audio signal yes. And the *etc* is for any other limitation/advantage that the hifiberry might have over a usb soundcard.

Comment: I just saw the typo in my first comment, that was supposed to be "latency: no" as in no difference - unless the USB device is low quality, then the Hifiberry will have lower latency ... i.e. hifiberry will be same or better in every respect

Comment: @JaromandaX That's great to hear. I'll try to get my hands on a hifiberry and give it a go if that's the case. Will post my findings regarding the differences here once I do. Thanks for the help man.